# Erlang bit syntax variable issue

Tags: erlang

Is there any way to format this so it's a valid expression, without adding another step?

```
<<One:8,_:(One*8)>> = <<1,9>>.
* 1: illegal bit size
```

These work

```
>> <<One:8,_:8>> = <<1,9>>.              
<<1,9>>

>> One*8.
8

>> <<One:8,_:(1*8)>> = <<1,9>>.
<<1,9>>

>> <<Eight:8,_:Eight>> = <<8,9>>.  
<<8,9>>
```

I'm trying to parse a binary with nested data with binary list comprehensions instead of stacking accumulators.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this ;-)

```
<<Size:8,_:Size/unit:8>> = <<1,9>>.
```

Comment: Thanks! That's perfect. In my case I set binary-unit:32 and the list comprehension I was messing with worked